# CORS blocked while fetching data using my node/express rest api server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, fetch

I have a running localhost node/express server which is supposed to allow any **post** request with some body and then return the same body with some message. I have used the **cors node package** for my express middlewares to allow CORS.

But I am facing a problem here, I can easily use post request from POSTMAN app within the system and get the output but when i try to fetch the request from other domains such as **codepen, jsfiddle**, I keep getting the **CORS blocked** response even though i have **allowed for cross origin resource sharing in my node server**.

Here's what i have done:

In My server side express app:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors({
  origin: "*",  //also tried: origin: "https://codepen.io"
  methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
  allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Authorization'
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());  // application/json

app.post('/post', (req, res, next) => {
    const title = req.body.title;
    const id = req.body.id;

    res.status(201).json({
        message: "POST request successful",
        resBody: {
            title: title,
            id: id
        }
    })
});

app.listen(4001);
```

For my client side javascript fetch code:

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    title: 'foo',
    id: 1
  }),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};

fetch('http://localhost:4001/post', options)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((jsonObject) => {
  console.log(jsonObject)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I get this message in the console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:4001/post. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

I know these types of questions have already been answered way too much time already, but i cant figure out why i still get the error after allowing CORS from my server.

Someone please explain.

Comment: You aren't properly handling preflights. Non-simple requests (such as yours, which has a different contentType than default) must send a preflight and the server must respond to it.

Comment: where do i have to handle them, in server side or in client side, and how do i do that? Can u please explain?

Comment: You're pretty close, you just need to make sure your CORS co nfiguration in node.js allows for OPTIONS requests and responds to them properly. The documentation for the module you are using should explain how.

Comment: I allowed the server for OPTIONS request as well, but i still get the same error. Does it have to do something with my clent side code? I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: The clientside doesn't need to be changed.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to pass the cors without any data in it? Because I had the same problem and I fixed it only by passing app.use(cors)
By default it open any origin, it's not secure at all but it works for me

Comment: Also, i get the connection ok(201) if i set the request header 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' in my fetch request but i can't see the data sent from server. I think the problem is with the content type application/json. Any idea?